# confused on forEach loop

Tags: discord.js

I am really confused on why this piece of code does not work how I intend it to work. Here is my code:

```
bot.on("message", async msg => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}apply`)) {
        let ban = BannedArray.forEach(banned => {
            if(msg.author.id === banned) {
                msg.delete()
                msg.channel.send("You are banned.")
            }
        })
        if (msg.channel.id === "771665046514040833") {
                    var user = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
                    const loading = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("Fetching your user ID...")
                    msg2 = await msg.channel.send(loading)
                    rapi.getUserIdFromUsername(user).then(async found => {
                        if (found === false) {
                            msg2.edit("test")
                        } else {
                            const found2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                .setTitle("User ID Found")
                                .setThumbnail(found.getAvatarBustImage)
                                .setDescription("We have found a User ID Linked to your account. It is: " + found.id + ". Is this you? \n [Click here to go to the profile](https://www.roblox.com/users/" + found.id + "/profile) \n \n ***PLEASE NOTE THAT IF YOU REACT WITH ✅ THAT YOUR ID WILL BE STORED FOR READING PURPOSES.***")
                            msg2.edit(found2)
                            msg.delete()
                            msg2.react('✅').then(r => {
                                msg2.react('❎');
                            });
                            msg2.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '❎' || reaction.emoji.name == '✅'),
                                { max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(async collected => {
                                    if (collected.first().emoji.name == '❎') {
                                        msg.reply("The ID has not been stored.")
                                    }
                                    if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✅') {
                                        IDarray.push(`${found.id} || ${found.name}`)
                                        console.log(found.id + " || " + found.name)
                                        bot.channels.cache.get("771406620570943548").send("New ID pushed to table. Use `idarray` to see the full list. \n Roblox ID of user: " + found.id + " \n Roblox Name: " + found.name)
                                        const check = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                            .setTitle("Success")
                                            .setDescription("Your ID has now been saved. Please open your DMs for this application so I can DM you. \n Question 1: \n Have you had experience with this job before?")
                                        msg3 = await msg2.edit(check)
                                        msg2.reactions.removeAll()
                                        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id
                                        msg3.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: false })
                                            .then(async collected => {
                                                const msg = collected.first()
                                                var Reply1 = msg.content.split(' ').slice(0).join(' ');
                                                if (msg.content === `${Reply1}`) {
                                                    msg.delete()
                                                    const ques2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                        .setTitle("Question 2")
                                                        .setDescription("Why should we choose you over other applicants?")
                                                    msg4 = await msg3.edit(ques2)
                                                    const filter2 = (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id
                                                    msg4.channel.awaitMessages(filter2, { max: 1, time: false })
                                                        .then(async collected => {
                                                            const msg = collected.first()
                                                            var Reply2 = msg.content.split(' ').slice(0).join(' ');
                                                            if (msg.content === `${Reply2}`) {
                                                                msg.delete()
                                                                const ques3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                    .setTitle("Question 3")
                                                                    .setDescription("What are the basic things that a DJ needs to do?")
                                                                msg5 = await msg4.edit(ques3)
                                                                const filter3 = (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id
                                                                msg5.channel.awaitMessages(filter3, { max: 1, time: false })
                                                                    .then(async collected => {
                                                                        const msg = collected.first()
                                                                        var Reply3 = msg.content.split(' ').slice(0).join(' ');
                                                                        if (msg.content === `${Reply3}`) {
                                                                            msg.delete()
                                                                            const ques4 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                                .setTitle("Question 4")
                                                                                .setDescription("How active are you from 1-10?")
                                                                            msg6 = await msg5.edit(ques4)
                                                                            const filter4 = (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id
                                                                            msg6.channel.awaitMessages(filter4, { max: 1, time: false })
                                                                                .then(async collected => {
                                                                                    const msg = collected.first()
                                                                                    var Reply4 = msg.content.split(' ').slice(0).join(' ');
                                                                                    if (msg.content === `${Reply4}`) {
                                                                                        msg.delete()
                                                                                        const ques5 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                                            .setTitle("Question 5")
                                                                                            .setDescription("Why should we deem to trust you?")
                                                                                        msg7 = await msg6.edit(ques5)
                                                                                        const filter5 = (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id
                                                                                        msg7.channel.awaitMessages(filter5, { max: 1, time: false })
                                                                                            .then(async collected => {
                                                                                                const msg = collected.first()
                                                                                                var Reply5 = msg.content.split(' ').slice(0).join(' ');
                                                                                                if (msg.content === `${Reply5}`) {
                                                                                                    msg.delete()
                                                                                                    const ques6 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                                                        .setTitle("Finished!")
                                                                                                        .setDescription("You have completed the application and it is being held for review. To either send or delete the application, please go to your DMs.")
                                                                                                    msg8 = await msg6.edit(ques6)
                                                                                                    msg9 = await msg.author.send("Here are all your answers, " + found.name + ". \n \n **Question 1,** Have you had experience with this job before? \n" + Reply1 + " \n \n **Question 2,** Why should we choose you over other applicants? \n" + Reply2 + " \n \n **Question 3,** What are the basic things that a DJ needs to do? \n" + Reply3 + " \n \n **Question 4,** How active are you from 1-10? \n" + Reply4 + " \n \n **Question 5,** Why should we deem to trust you? \n" + Reply5 + " \n \n **Please choose to either send or delete the application below.**")
                                                                                                    msg9.react('✅').then(r => {
                                                                                                        msg9.react('❎');
                                                                                                    });
                                                                                                    msg9.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '❎' || reaction.emoji.name == '✅'),
                                                                                                        { max: 1, time: false }).then(async collected => {
                                                                                                            if (collected.first().emoji.name == '❎') {
                                                                                                                msg9.reactions.removeAll()
                                                                                                                msg9.edit("The application has not been sent.")
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                            if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✅') {
                                                                                                                const app = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                                                                    .setTitle("New application from `" + msg.author.username + "`")
                                                                                                                    .setDescription("Answers from: " + found.name + ". \n \n **Question 1,** Have you had experience with this job before? \n" + Reply1 + " \n \n **Question 2,** Why should we choose you over other applicants? \n" + Reply2 + " \n \n **Question 3,** What are the basic things that a DJ needs to do? \n" + Reply3 + " \n \n **Question 4,** How active are you from 1-10? \n" + Reply4 + " \n \n **Question 5,** Why should we deem to trust you? \n" + Reply5)
                                                                                                                bot.channels.cache.get("771671063909761044").send(app)
                                                                                                                msg9.edit("Your application has been sent! Keep an eye on the jobs channel to see if you passed!")
                                                                                                                msg9.reactions.removeAll()
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                        })
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            })
                                                                                    }
                                                                                })
                                                                        }
                                                                    })
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                                }
                                            })
                                    }
                                }).catch(() => {
                                    msg.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');
                                    msg2.reactions.removeAll()
                                });
                        }
                    })
        } else {
            msg.delete()
            msg.author.send("You can only use the command `--apply` in the application channel (<#771665046514040833>)")
        }
    }
})
```

In this script it checks to see if someone is banned but if they are, the command goes ahead. I do get an error saying this: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message. I am really confused since I have used this method in other bots I have made. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Could you show which line the error is referencing?

Comment: I think it is Line 4

Comment: `if(msg.author.id === banned) {`?

Comment: Or maybe 6 im not sure

Comment: Could you double-check?

Comment: This is the whole error: (node:10648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\DJApp Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)        
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
That is all I could fit in